# Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'accessing _cachedSystemAnimationFence requires the main thread

Tags: ios, multithreading, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I am developing with Xamarin.IOS.
I received a lot of such crash report from users.

The crash reports look like this:

```
    Incident Identifier: 21D06ED3-DE8E-4872-B75F-19D5B350E406
    CrashReporter Key:   07432D3F-8FFD-427B-A2C6-6B6E77AF5223
    Hardware Model:      iPhone7,2
    Process:         ****
    Path:            ****
    Identifier:      ****
    Version:         ****
    Code Type:       ARM-64
    Parent Process:  ??? [1]

    Date/Time:       2017-02-08T14:54:58Z
    Launch Time:     2017-02-08T14:54:50Z
    OS Version:      iPhone OS 10.2.1 (14D27)
    Report Version:  104

    Exception Type:  SIGABRT
    Exception Codes: #0 at 0x18d3d7014
    Crashed Thread:  13

    Application Specific Information:
    *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'accessing _cachedSystemAnimationFence requires the main thread'

    Last Exception Backtrace:
    0   CoreFoundation                       0x000000018e4091b8 0x18e2d9000 + 1245624
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                      0x000000018ce4055c 0x18ce38000 + 34140
    2   CoreFoundation                       0x000000018e40908c 0x18e2d9000 + 1245324
    3   Foundation                           0x000000018eec102c 0x18ee13000 + 712748
    4   UIKit                                0x000000019453f690 0x1942af000 + 2688656
    5   UIKit                                0x0000000194596d70 0x1942af000 + 3046768
    6   UIKit                                0x0000000194379e7c 0x1942af000 + 831100
    7   UIKit                                0x00000001942c5448 0x1942af000 + 91208
    8   UIKit                                0x0000000194334308 0x1942af000 + 545544
    9   UIKit                                0x00000001943ba318 0x1942af000 + 1094424
    10  UIKit                                0x0000000194629488 0x1942af000 + 3646600
    11  UIKit                                0x00000001a25d47e0 0x1a2584000 + 329696
    12  UIKit                                0x000000019462adec 0x1942af000 + 3653100
    13  UIKit                                0x000000019462d62c 0x1942af000 + 3663404
    14  UIKit                                0x00000001942cc7dc 0x1942af000 + 120796
    15  UIKit                                0x000000019462d59c 0x1942af000 + 3663260
    16  UIKit                                0x000000019462d920 0x1942af000 + 3664160
    17  UIKit                                0x00000001943b1154 0x1942af000 + 1057108
    18  UIKit                                0x00000001a25d40dc 0x1a2584000 + 327900
...
Thread 13 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib               0x000000018d3d7014 0x18d3b8000 + 126996
1   libsystem_c.dylib                    0x000000018d34b400 0x18d2e8000 + 406528
2   GIVCONVEYiOS                         0x000000010019fd90 0x1000f8000 + 687504
3   GIVCONVEYiOS                         0x000000010010606c 0x1000f8000 + 57452
4   CoreFoundation                       0x000000018e409538 0x18e2d9000 + 1246520
5   libobjc.A.dylib                      0x000000018ce40838 0x18ce38000 + 34872
6   GIVCONVEYiOS                         0x000000010018dadc 0x1000f8000 + 613084
7   libc++abi.dylib                      0x000000018ce2f66c 0x18ce14000 + 112236
8   libc++abi.dylib                      0x000000018ce2ef84 0x18ce14000 + 110468
9   libobjc.A.dylib                      0x000000018ce40690 0x18ce38000 + 34448
10  CoreFoundation                       0x000000018e40908c 0x18e2d9000 + 1245324
11  Foundation                           0x000000018eec102c 0x18ee13000 + 712748
12  UIKit                                0x000000019453f690 0x1942af000 + 2688656
13  UIKit                                0x0000000194596d70 0x1942af000 + 3046768
14  UIKit                                0x0000000194379e7c 0x1942af000 + 831100
15  UIKit                                0x00000001942c5448 0x1942af000 + 91208
16  UIKit                                0x0000000194334308 0x1942af000 + 545544
17  UIKit                                0x00000001943ba318 0x1942af000 + 1094424
18  UIKit                                0x0000000194629488 0x1942af000 + 3646600
19  UIKit                                0x00000001a25d47e0 0x1a2584000 + 329696
20  UIKit                                0x000000019462adec 0x1942af000 + 3653100
21  UIKit                                0x000000019462d62c 0x1942af000 + 3663404
22  UIKit                                0x00000001942cc7dc 0x1942af000 + 120796
23  UIKit                                0x000000019462d59c 0x1942af000 + 3663260
24  UIKit                                0x000000019462d920 0x1942af000 + 3664160
...
```

Since it didn't present the stacktrace, it is very hard to narrow down the suspicious code area.  From the error message, it indicated that thread 13 crashed because it updated the UI.

I know thread 13 is a background thread. 
Q: How can I narrow down this issue? Or can we track down this issue by detect if it is on Mainthread before every UI updating?

I tried to symbolcate and get a little more information.

Tried to Symbolicate and get a little more information. Thread 15 Crashed:

```
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib               0x0000000187543014 __pthread_kill + 8
1   libsystem_c.dylib                    0x00000001874b7400 abort + 140
2   GIVCONVEYiOS                         0x000000010013bd90 0x100094000 + 687504
3   GIVCONVEYiOS                         0x00000001000a206c 0x100094000 + 57452
4   CoreFoundation                       0x0000000188575538 __handleUncaughtException + 644
5   libobjc.A.dylib                      0x0000000186fac838 _objc_terminate() + 112
6   GIVCONVEYiOS                         0x0000000100129adc 0x100094000 + 613084
7   libc++abi.dylib                      0x0000000186f9b66c std::__terminate(void (*)()) + 16
8   libc++abi.dylib                      0x0000000186f9af84 __cxxabiv1::exception_cleanup_func(_Unwind_Reason_Code, _Unwind_Exception*) + 0
9   libobjc.A.dylib                      0x0000000186fac690 _objc_exception_destructor(void*) + 0
10  CoreFoundation                       0x000000018857508c +[NSException raise:format:arguments:] + 104
11  Foundation                           0x000000018902d02c -[NSAssertionHandler handleFailureInMethod:object:file:lineNumber:description:] + 112
12  UIKit                                0x000000018e6ab690 -[UIApplication _cachedSystemAnimationFenceCreatingIfNecessary:] + 196
13  UIKit                                0x000000018e702d70 +[UIWindow _synchronizeDrawingWithPreCommitHandler:] + 68
14  UIKit                                0x000000018e4e5e7c -[UIApplication _setStatusBarHidden:animationParameters:changeApplicationFlag:] + 700
15  UIKit                                0x000000018e431448 -[UIApplication _updateCurrentStatusBarViewControllerAppearance] + 436
16  UIKit                                0x000000018e4a0308 -[UIViewController setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate] + 204
17  UIKit                                0x000000018e526318 -[UIViewController _setPresentedStatusBarViewController:] + 96
18  UIKit                                0x000000018e795488 -[UIViewController _presentViewController:modalSourceViewController:presentationController:animationController:interactionController:completion:] + 1512
19  UIKit                                0x000000019c7407e0 -[UIViewControllerAccessibility _presentViewController:modalSourceViewController:presentationController:animationController:interactionController:completion:] + 256
20  UIKit                                0x000000018e796dec -[UIViewController _presentViewController:withAnimationController:completion:] + 4524
21  UIKit                                0x000000018e79962c __62-[UIViewController presentViewController:animated:completion:]_block_invoke_2 + 68
22  UIKit                                0x000000018e4387dc +[UIView(Animation) performWithoutAnimation:] + 104
23  UIKit                                0x000000018e79959c __62-[UIViewController presentViewController:animated:completion:]_block_invoke + 312
24  UIKit                                0x000000018e799920 -[UIViewController _performCoordinatedPresentOrDismiss:animated:] + 524
25  UIKit                                0x000000018e51d154 -[UIViewController presentViewController:animated:completion:] + 184
26  UIKit                                0x000000019c7400dc -[UIViewControllerAccessibility presentViewController:animated:completion:] + 204
27  GIVCONVEYiOS                         0x00000001003a59b0 0x100094000 + 3217840
28  GIVCONVEYiOS                         0x0000000100341b08 0x100094000 + 2808584
29  GIVCONVEYiOS                         0x0000000100fce0a0 0x100094000 + 15966368
30  GIVCONVEYiOS                         0x0000000100fceee4 0x100094000 + 15970020
31  GIVCONVEYiOS                         0x0000000100fd48dc 0x100094000 + 15993052
```

How can I locate the code with this line of information : 27  GIVCONVEYiOS                         0x00000001003a59b0 0x100094000 + 3217840

Comment: All UI work should be done on the main thread. Wrap your call with a `dispatch_async` or equivalent for Xamarin.

Comment: Symbolicate your crash report  to get some detail on the stack trace:  https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/troubleshooting/questions/symbolicate-ios-crash/

Comment: Tried to Symbolicate and get a little more information